# Delta function as lorentzian curve. Separation radial and angular part in 2D.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, dirac-delta

We know that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2 + x^2} = \delta(x).$$

This is because the function has a constant unit integral over $\mathbb{R}$ and is increasingly localized as we approach the limit.

If we consider the functions $\eta_{\varepsilon} : \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$
$$\eta_{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2 + \mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{r}},$$
we have a diverging integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ for finite $\varepsilon$, so the limit is indeterminate.

However, in polar coordinates, we could write the $\eta_{\varepsilon}$ function as depending only on the radial variable. Can we then formally take the following limit?
\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\varepsilon r f(r)}{\varepsilon^2+r^2} \mathrm{d}r = 2\pi rf(r) \Big|_{r=0},
\end{align}
which also solves the indeterminacy in the limit for the integral of $\eta_{\varepsilon}$ concluding that it's zero.

Edit: Thanks to @Klaus I think that the question can be formulated differently. For the functions $\zeta_{\varepsilon} : \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$
$$\zeta_{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{r}) =  \frac{1}{\pi^2 \sqrt{\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{r}}} \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2 + \mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{r}},$$
the integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ is one independently of $\varepsilon$.

Does the following hold?
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \zeta_{\varepsilon} = \delta(||\mathbf{r}||)$$

If it does, it must also hold
$$\frac{1}{\pi^2} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \eta_{\varepsilon} = ||\mathbf{r}|| \delta(||\mathbf{r}||).$$

Or is this reasoning flawed?

Comment: I think that in order to have the RHS you desire, you should not make the ordinary product with $\varepsilon/(\varepsilon^2+t^2)$,  but **convolve** with it.

Comment: @JeanMarie note that I am evaluating at $r=0$ on the RHS, it is effectively a convolution with the new variable taken to 0

Comment: Understood. My comment is based on the fact that $\delta$ is neutral for convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this does not converge, take for example $f \equiv 1$:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\varepsilon r}{\varepsilon^2 + r^2} \, \mathrm{d}r = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\log(\varepsilon^2 +r^2)\big|_0^{\infty} = \infty.$$
What you can do, however, take any non-negative $\eta \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $\|\eta\|_1 = 1$. Then $\eta_{\varepsilon}(x) := \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\eta(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})$ defines a Dirac sequence.

Comment: This is precisely what I said in the post, for any finite $\varepsilon$ it is diverging, but as we take the limit we have an indeterminate product of the form $0 \infty$. The integral that you are writing in the limit of $\varepsilon \to 0$ and replacing $r \to f(r)$ any smooth function is $f(0)$ [(the lorentzian is a nascent delta function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem#Proof_of_the_real_version)  when working on $\mathbb{R}$ what confuses me is whether it is valid when working in higher dimensions

Comment: @ÁlexDeLaCalzada Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are asking, but the integral you are linking is converging for every $\varepsilon$. The difference between 1D and 2D is that $\frac{1}{1+\|r\|^2}$ is integrable in 1D but not in 2D. You could take $\frac{1}{1+\|r\|^3}$ instead, of course.

Comment: Then if I consider $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\pi ||r||} \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2 + ||r||^2}$ this is certainly a $\delta(||r||)$, right? would that imply that what I'm writing there is $||r|| \delta(||r||)$?
Edit: maybe with some extra $1/(2\pi)$

Comment: @ÁlexDeLaCalzada Yes, that should be ok as long you are considering it for functions $f$ that only depend on $\|r\|$ and not on $\phi$. Maybe check the constant pre-factor again. I think it should be $\frac{1}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: The Dirac Delta operates on test functions (i.e., funcitons that are smooth and  have compact support).  The function $f\equiv 1$ is not a suitable test function.  That said, the function $\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2+y^2}$ is not a nascent Dirac Delta.